# Xamarin Binding Library - missing Java references

Tags: xamarin, bindings-library

We have a couple of ELO touch tablets and status lights and a jar file ("eloperipherallib.jar") to change the color of the status light. Though we are not Java developers, we were able to create an .apk (with Android Studio) and change the color of the status light using this jar.

We now want to do the same in .NET, using Xamarin. We therefore created an "Android Bindings Library (Xamarin)" and added the jar (following the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/binding-a-jar). When building the bindings library we get the following warnings:

```
warning BG8605: The Java type 'android.elo.peripheral.ELOPeripheralEventListener' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
warning BG8605: The Java type 'android.elo.peripheral.ELOPeripheralManager' could not be found (are you missing a Java reference jar/aar or a Java binding library NuGet?)
warning BG8606: Some types or members could not be bound because referenced Java types could not be found. See the 'java-resolution-report.log' file for details.
```

And at runtime we get a similar exception when "ELOPeripheralManager" is used.

Now, we do not have this problem in the .apk created with Android Studio, so I guess the jar file contains everything that is needed. We just can't figure out what the Xamarin project is missing, if that what's missing is in the jar file anywhere and/or how we can get it out of the jar file and put it in the Xamarin project so it'll build…

Can someone point us in the right direction?

Comment: As that doc says **"We'll illustrate with an example where everything goes right – that is, where no customization or debugging of bindings is required."** After that sentence, it gives a link to the **advanced** documentation, which describes changes you might need to make manually. Sounds like you've run into such a situation.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I used the advanced documentation to add a couple of lines to "Metadata.xml" to get rid of some errors. The warnings that remain are the only ones I can't seem to solve...

Comment: Have you walk through[troubleshooting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/binding-java-library/troubleshooting-bindings)  to get the issue resolved?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT In did walk through the troubleshooting. It states 'Identify the unreferenced library and add those dependencies to the Xamarin.Android binding project ...'. The jar-file I'm trying to use has import statements like 'android.elo.peripheral.xxx'. That corresponds to the warnings I'm getting. So my conclusion is/was: I'm missing some referenced libraries. But I'm unable to find this missing library... Android Studio builds the project without any problems though, I just can't figure out where Android Studio gets this 'missing' library from...

Comment: From my point of view,I think you need add package reference in your project setting.However,I can't figure out what package reference you need add.You could refer to this [similar link](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6650) .